# GridDB:Installation WSL - The system hasn't been booted with systemd as the init system (PID 1). Connection to the bus has failed: Host is down

Tags: ubuntu, wsl-2, griddb

I'm encountering an issue while trying to install gridDB on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) by following the instructions provided in the gridDB installation section here.

When I attempt to start gridDB using the command sudo systemctl start gridstore, I receive the following error:
`The system hasn't been booted with systemd as the init system (PID 1). It's not possible to proceed. Connection to the bus has failed: Host is down.`

I've attempted this installation on various versions of Ubuntu (18.04, 20.04, and 22.04), but I haven't been able to resolve this issue.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to resolve this systemd error and successfully install gridDB on WSL?